# extjs - add combobox inside grid panel header ... where the title lays

Tags: extjs, grid

is there a way to add a combobox box to this part of a grid header?  I can't seem to find any examples when I look in sencha docs.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, take a look at the [header](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-header)  config. You might specify your custom items in here.

```
    header: {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combo',
            queryMode: 'local',
            store: ['male', 'female']
        }]
    }
```

Here is the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qfb